# Any way to speed up this python code (point in polygon)?

Tags: python-2.7, geospatial, r-sp, shapely, point-in-polygon

I have two files, one with points and its id. Another one with polygons and its id and some more columns. I am trying to get the polygon id associated with each point. I have nearly 1.7 million points and 50000 polygons. And the point in polygon check is running forever in IPython notebook, Is there a way to optimise my code here or may be use multiprocessing module and do parallel process to speed up the point in polygon check?

First reading the polygon file.

```
import shapefile
import shapely
polygons_sf = shapefile.Reader("ploygonshapefile.shp")
polygon_shapes = polygons_sf.shapes()
polygon_points = [q.points for q in polygon_shapes]
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
polygons = [Polygon(q) for q in polygon_points]
polygons_sf_records = polygons_sf.records() #To get the polygon id
```

Then creating an rtree index for the polygon

```
from rtree import index
idx = index.Index() #creating an rtree
count = -1
for a,b in zip(polygon_shapes,polygons_sf_records):
    count +=1
    idx.insert(count,a.bbox,obj=b[1])
```

Then loading in the point file.

```
points_sf = shapefile.Reader("pointshapefile.shp")
point_shapes = points_sf.iterShapes()
#Creating points as list to iterate
point_coords= [q.points[0] for q in point_shapes]
from shapely.geometry import Point
points = [Point(q.points[0]) for q in point_shapes]
points_sf_records = points_sf.records() #To get the point id
```

Then trying to find out the polygon id for each point.

```
matches = []
for i in range(len(points)): #Iterate through each point
    temp= None
    #Iterate only through the bounding boxes which contain the point
    for j in idx.intersection(point_coords[i]):
    #Verify that point is within the polygon itself not just the bounding box
        if points[i].within(polygons[j]):
            temp=j
            break
            matches.append({'Point_id' : points_sf_recods[i][0],'Polygon_id' : polygons_sf_records[j][1]}) #Either the first match found, or None for no matches
```

Comment: do your polygons overlap or something? otherwise that should be pretty fast

Comment: Nope. Doesn't have overlapping polygons. :(

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Yes if you can. Thanks.

Comment: To better understand the problem, let me ask you some questions. 1) Is this something you need to do regularly or is it a one time processing you need to do? 2) Did you measure how much time is needed to process only a portion of the points? (in order to know if parallel processing with several cores can solve this, we need to know that). 3) Do you have any other extra info about the points that would allow us to spatially classify them? 4) do you know the maximum and minimum coordinates of all the polygons? (to build a box that contains them all). 5) please, provide some data samples.